# Side Collisions

Tags: java, collision

I'm making a tilemap game and I've got the simple collisions down.  However to make the game work I have to know which side of the rectangle hit the wall/brick.  Just putting a simple collision code inside of the main collision:

```
if(spriteX < brickX + brickwidth) {}
```

doesn't work.  The main collision code at the moment is:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < 31; counter++) {

    if(spriteX + 40 >= collisionX[counter] && collisionX[counter] + 100 >= spriteX 
    && spriteY + 40 >= collisionY[counter] && collisionY[counter] + 100 >= spriteY) {

        velX = 0;
        velY = 0;

        collisions = counter;

    } else {

        if(counter == collisions && jumping == false) {

            fall();                 
        }               
    }           
}
```

If you want the entire class:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

// dimensions

public static final int width = 800;
public static final int height = 800;
public static final int scale = 1;

// main loop

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private int FPS = 60;
private int targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

// drawing

private Graphics2D g;
private BufferedImage image;

int x;
int y;

boolean makeCollision = false;

// sprite

int spriteX = 210;
int spriteY = 200;
int velX = 0;
int velY = 10;

public boolean notOnGround = true;

int counter;
int collisionsCounter;
int jumps = 0;

public int row;
public int column;

public boolean collision;
public boolean jumping = false;

public String side = null;

// tilemap

int[][] map = {

        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

};

int[] collisionX = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    };
int[] collisionY = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    };
int[] jump =       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    };
int collisions;

public Panel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();

}

public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();

    if(thread == null) {

        running = true;
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

}

public void init() {

    image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

}

public void update() {

    if(spriteY < jump[0]) {

        System.out.println(jump[0]);

        jumping = false;

        fall();

    }

}

public void draw() {

    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    for(column = 0; column <= 7; column++) {

        x = 0;

        for(row = 0; row <= 7; row++) {

            changeColor(row, column, g);

            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

            x = x + 100;

        }

        y = y + 100;

    }

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(spriteX, spriteY, 40, 40);

    spriteX += velX;
    spriteY += velY;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < 31; counter++) {

        if(spriteX + 40 >= collisionX[counter] && collisionX[counter] + 100 >= spriteX 
        && spriteY + 40 >= collisionY[counter] && collisionY[counter] + 100 >= spriteY){

            velX = 0;
            velY = 0;

            collisions = counter;

        } else {

            if(counter == collisions && jumping == false) {

                fall();

            }

        }

    }

}

public void changeColor(int rowGive, int columnGive, Graphics g) {

    if(map[rowGive][columnGive] == 1) {

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        if(counter < 30) {

            collisionX[counter] = x;
            collisionY[counter] = y;

        }

        counter++;

    } else {

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

}

public void fall() {

    velY = 5;

}

public void drawToScreen() {

    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width * scale, height * scale, null);
    g2.dispose();

}

public void run() {

    init();

    long wait;
    long elapsed;
    long start;

    while(running) {

        start = System.nanoTime();
        update();
        draw();
        drawToScreen();

        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        if(wait < 0) wait = 5;

        try {

            thread.sleep(wait);

        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

        velX = 5;

    }
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        velX = -5;

    }
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && jumping == false) {

        jumping = true;

        velY = -5;
        jump[0] = spriteY - 100;

    }

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {



}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to divide the problem a little bit. You don't need to find out when a rectange hit a wall: you need to find when the **left side of the rectangle** hit the **right side of the wall** and when the **right side of the rectangle** hit the **left side of the wall**.

To be more precise: **don't test objects**. Divide your object in collision surfaces (left and right sides in your case), find a way to modelize them (usually x and x+width are the left and right side of your rectangle, if x is the x coordinate of your topleft corner). And test both at the same time with an "or" condition.

```
if(spriteX < brickX + brickwidth || spriteX + spritewidth > brickX) {}
```

*edit* Reading your complete class a little more closely, it looks like you do something similar but you use "&&" condition, meaning you can never be true since both side collisions cannot happen at the same time. But I may be wrong, can you tell me ?

Comment: When I did that, it was always true.  No matter what side was hit, there was always a collision with all (or more than one) of them (according to my collision detection).

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly about your collision problem I've noticed a "bug" in `draw()` that is causing your `map` array to be displayed flipped around the -45 angle.

You should be incrementing y when row is incremented and x when column is incremented.  Do this and your display will look the same as your `map` initialization code.

In other words this:

```
public void draw() {

    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    for(column = 0; column <= 7; column++) {

        y = 0;

        for(row = 0; row <= 7; row++) {

            changeColor(row, column, g);

            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

            y = y + 100;

        }

        x = x + 100;

    }
...
```

will make this

```
int[][] map = {

        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

};
```

look like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]